# BigQuery bq command with asterisk (*) doesn't work in Compute Engine

Tags: google-bigquery, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have a directory with a file named `file1.txt`

And I run the command:

`bq query "SELECT * FROM [publicdata:samples.shakespeare] LIMIT 5"`

In my local machine it works fine but in Compute Engine I receive this error:

> Waiting on bqjob_r2aaecf624e10b8c5_0000014d0537316e_1 ... (0s) Current status: DONE
>   BigQuery error in query operation: Error processing job 'my-project-id:bqjob_r2aaecf624e10b8c5_0000014d0537316e_1': Field 'file1.txt' not found.

If the directory is empty it works fine. I'm guessing the asterisk is expanding the file(s) into the query but I don't know why.

Comment: The shell is expanding the *, you need to escape it.

See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/372807/avoid-expansion-of-in-bash-builtin-function-let

Comment: Tried to escape it with backslash and `set -f` but it doesn't work..

Comment: What shell are you using? It works fine with my GCE bash. (run 'ps -p $$')

Comment: I'm using bash on Ubuntu machine. `uname- a` output: Linux <machine-name> 3.16.0-36-generic #48~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Apr 15 13:11:28 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently the `bq` command which is located at `/usr/bin/bq` has the following script:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec /usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/bin/bq ${@}
```

which expands the asterisk.

As a current workaround I'm calling `/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/bin/bq` directly.